# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Quicksort Algorithm

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, quicksort

So this is my code. The error is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, below I have mentioned it. Please help me find the cause.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sort {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of entries");
        int[] arr = new int[s.nextInt()];
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            arr[i] = s.nextInt();
        s.close();
        QuickSort.sort(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
}

public class QuickSort {

    private static int partition(int[] arr, int hi, int lo){
        int i=lo,j=hi+1,swap=0;
        while(true){
            while(arr[++i]<arr[lo])
                if(i==hi)break;
            while(arr[--j]>arr[lo]) \\error line
                if(j==lo)break;
            if(j<=i)break;
            swap=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=swap;
        }
        swap=arr[lo];
        arr[lo]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=swap;
        return j;   
    }
    public static void sort(int[] arr){
        sort(arr,arr.length-1,0);
    }
    private static void sort(int[] arr,int hi,int lo){
        int j = partition(arr,hi,lo);
        sort(arr,j-1,lo);
        sort(arr,hi,j+1);
    }

}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at riku.QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:10) at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:28) at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:29) at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:29) at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:29) at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:25) at riku.sort.main(sort.java:12) this is the complete error log

Comment: In the exception you get the line number where it is thrown, it should help you (and us if you show us which line it is)

Comment: What is the error message? It should give you the line number the error occurred on, and the value of the offending index.

Comment: i have showed it in the comment with \\error line

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at riku.QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:10)
 at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:28)
 at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:29)
 at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:29)
 at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:29)
 at riku.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:25)
 at riku.sort.main(sort.java:12)

this is the complete error log

Comment: And what is the value of the index as reported by the error message?

Comment: So either j is -1 or lo is -1.

Comment: lo is 0...j is -1 that much i figured but i have a check on j that it breaks off the loops when j==lo..so i dont get how j is -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` getting to 0, then `arr[--j]` is evaluating to `arr[-1]` you have to make sure that index never gets below zero.

Another approach would be to use recursion, it would be much simpler but can cause stack overflow for large arrays.

Comment: then why doesnt it break off at j==lo?

Comment: When it gets there it already evaluated the condition in the loop, what generates the error.

Comment: set j=hi
and then j-- ?
inplace of j=hi+1
and --j

Comment: Just change from `while(arr[--j]>arr[lo])` to `while(arr[j--]>arr[lo])`. Overall the code is error prone, does your implementation has to be in-place?

Comment: `while(arr[--j]>arr[lo]) 
                if(j==lo)break;`  will always exit with j>=0 as long as j was > 0 initially. So the problem seems to be that j can start out equal to zero.

Comment: i have just started coding...how do i minimise my code to errors?
and no implementation doesnt have to be in place

Comment: initialised j to hi+1..dont know how it could be <0

Comment: yeah i think thats it FredK..
thanks for the help
although i dont know how to solve it

Comment: `int j = partition(arr,hi,lo);` can set j<2, then the you call `sort(arr,j-1,lo);` so the second argument is less than 1.
`

Comment: A few tips: 1. Don't use arrays directly in java, use ArrayList so you have the List abstraction but backed up by array. 2. Use java.util.stream.Collectors.partitioningBy to partition your set in smaller and equalOrGreater. 3. Use an recursive algorithm, `List<Comparable> sort(List<Comparable> unorderedList)` and after your  select the pivot and make the partition all your program has to do is `return sort(smaller).addAll(Arrays.asList(pivot)).addAll(sort(equalOrGreater);`. No more mess with array indexes :)

Comment: On the beginning of this method you have to put `if (unorderedList.isEmpty()) return unorderedList;` in the `else` put the algorithm I described before. This will stop the recursion when the list finally gets empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your `--` is **before** your variable `j`, which means that the variable first is decreased, then read.

Try to put it **after** the variable like this: `arr[j--]`.

If it won't work, try setting `j=hi+1`to `j=hi`.

Comment: tried that!
error is in the swap line now after the while loop

Comment: Now you're out of the upper bound of the array? Wouldn't that mean, that the `i` has the same problem as the `j` had? Try to change the increasing for `i` from `++i` to `i++`.

Comment: no the post decrement of j
is causing it to give an error after the while loop has completed on a different line
the line where i m swapping
same j same error different line

Comment: Your problem lies deeper. I reproduced your error and the problem is that `j` is returned from `partition()` and in that moment `j` is always 0, what means that the second argument (int hi) in `partition` is always 0. This leads to the effect that `j` is -1 at the second call.

Comment: yup...i got it thanx :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. This way the break statement is not needed.

```java
while(j >= 0 && arr[j] > arr[lo])
    j--;
```